# Big matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $U,A \in \mathbb{R}^{m x n}$, $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^p$, $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^q$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let also the two vectors of square matrices,

$K_a^i \in \mathbb{R}^{mxm}, i=1,2,...p$ and $K_b^j \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}, j=1,2,...q$.

Given the equation

$J = \parallel U - (\sum_i a_iK_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\parallel_F^2 + c\parallel \mathbf{a} \parallel_2$

where $\parallel \cdot \parallel_F$ stands for the Frobenius norm.
Is the following derivation correct? (making $\frac{dJ}{da_i}=0$)

\begin{align*}
\frac{dJ}{da_i} &= 2 \left[U-(\sum_i a_iK_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]\left[-(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right] + 2ca_i = 0 \\
&= \left[U-(\sum_i a_iK_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right] + ca_i\left[-(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ = 0 \\
& -ca_i\left[-(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ - (\sum_i a_iK_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T = -U\\
& a_ic\left[(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ + a_iK_a^iA(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T + (\sum_{s \neq i} a_sK_a^s)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T = U\\
& a_i\left[c\left[(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ + K_a^iA(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right] = U - (\sum_{s \neq i} a_sK_a^s)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T \\
a_i &= \left[U - (\sum_{s \neq i} a_sK_a^s)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]\left[c\left[(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ + K_a^iA(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)^T\right]^+ \\
\end{align*}
where $M^+$ is the pseudoinverse of the matrix $M$.

In case of being correct, is it possible to simplify it more?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your derivative expressions, the $b$-terms have acquired a transpose which wasn't present in your initial expression for $J$. So should the $b$-matrices be transposed or not?  It might clarify your thinking to consider the case where all of the matrices are rectangular.

Comment: I'm sorry, the initial expression of J was wrong, I added this to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative expression needs a [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)  instead of a regular matrix product in the first term on the RHS,
$$\eqalign{
\frac{dJ}{da_i} &= 2 \bigg[U-(\sum_n a_nK_a^n)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)\bigg] : \bigg[-(K_a^i)A(\sum_j b_jK_b^j)\bigg] + 2ca_i \cr
}$$
in order to make all of the terms scalar-valued.  Otherwise you are adding a matrix to a scalar, and that doesn't make sense.

Also, you should not use the free-index $i$ (on the LHS) as a summation-index (on the RHS), that will only lead to confusion.  You'll notice that I've changed the summation-index to $n$.

The reason for the Frobenius product comes from the fact that the Frobenius norm of a matrix (and its differential) can be written in terms of the Frobenius product 
$$\eqalign{
  \|M\|_F^2 &= M:M \cr\cr
  d\,\|M\|_F^2 &= 2\,M:dM \cr
}$$
Also, since this question doesn't concern them, you might want to replace the summations over the $b$-coefficients with a single matrix term to reduce some of the clutter, e.g.
$$ B = \sum_j b_jK_b^j $$

**Update**

Thinking about this some more, if you define a new set of matrices
$$\eqalign{
  M_i = K_a^i\,AB \cr
}$$
then you can write the derivative expression as
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{1}{2} \frac{dJ}{da_i} &= \bigg[\sum_k a_k M_k - U\bigg]:M_i + ca_i \cr
 &= \sum_k a_k M_k:M_i - U:M_i + ca_i \cr
}$$
To simplify things, define a new matrix and vector whose elements are given by
$$\eqalign{
  X_{ik} &= M_k:M_i \cr
  v_{i} &= U:M_i \cr
}$$
Since the Frobenius product is commutative, the matrix is symmetric.

Setting the derivative to zero, you can write a standard matrix-vector equation
$$\eqalign{
  (X+cI)\,a &= v \cr
}$$
which you can easily solve for $a$.